# Delphi - undeclared identifier: LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT

Tags: delphi, format, delphi-2010, locale, undefined

I'm trying to format a float (extended) by the system locale's default currency settings.  I have found the key proponent to this solution to be the following line:

`GetLocaleFormatSettings(LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT, format_settings);`

and everywhere I look, they provide the solution exactly as shown (no class specifier before, like System.LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT or anything).  However, my compiler is insistent that LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT is an undeclared identifier.  It *seems* to me that the only requirement is to have "uses SysUtils", which I do.

I'm using Delphi 2010.  Does anybody know why my compiler can't find this seemingly implicit constant?

Thanks in abundance,

Jared

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Add Windows to your uses list. That identifier is defined there.